# What is the purpose of reactDOM in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-redux, react-dom, virtual-dom

Explanation: why reactjs use virtual Dom concept, how does it different from orginal Dom.
Explain with suitable example .
Also explain how react Dom render jsx components

How react virtual Dom works explain in a simple words .

Comment: It's great that you're looking to understand React better, but this type of question isn't suitable for Stackoverflow. It is too broad. I would encourage you to take the [tour] and check the [ask] page for more information on what is appropriate for this site. For this question, I would recommend just searching for articles on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

When a user interacts with a React application, the virtual DOM is updated with the new state of the application. React then calculates the difference between the previous and current virtual DOM, and updates only the parts of the actual DOM that need to be changed. This approach reduces the number of DOM manipulations required, which results in better performance and faster updates to the user interface.